# Browser based interface to a local mailbox in mbox format

Tags: linux, web-browser, email-client

We have an `mbox` file on the NFS file server that stores a copy of all internal communication. I would like to set up a web interface (within an Apache instance) so that everyone can use their browser to search through the mails and browse the threads, similar to the `mailman` interface.

Are there any free open-source tools for Linux that I can use for this purpose? Mailman seems a bit of an overkill, since I don't need to manage the mailing lists, just give a nice browser interface to a single mailbox.